# Highlight StartDate to EndDate Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i highlight Dates from StartDate to EndDate using asp Calendar C#

when i first Click a Date to Calendar it will be the first Date and when i Click another Date i will be the last Date and highlights the Date

from StartDate to EndDate

I hope someone can answer my question

Comment: Why do you need this?  I suspect there's a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Assuming you cannot `DELETE` rows from the table, and the increment is always 1, then you should just be able to select the greatest ID in the table & add 1 to it.

Comment: @DennisTraub i don't know how to get the next Auto Increment Value. Can you help me?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: that is an extremely naive approach.  In a single user environment this is fine, but add even one more user and you will start encountering problems.

Comment: @CarloAdap: Understand that once you get that number there is no longer any guarantee that it will remain that number.  A record could be inserted immediately after you fetch the number, for example.  I _really_ suspect there's a better approach to your problem, we just don't know what that problem is.

Comment: @CarloAdap: This kind of question is a HUGE red flag that typically indicates the developer does not understand his tools.  You might try posting what design consideration you are trying to implement and see what the recommended course of action is.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - `Max( RoomId ) + 1` doesn't always work well when executed in parallel by multiple clients.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be able to get the next auto-increment value until you actually insert the data.  Think about it, suppose you query for the next ID, it tells you '2', and then someone else comes in and inserts a row.  Which ID should it get?  '2'? '3'?

When you insert the data you can query `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to find the last inserted ID in your scope.

Comment: Indeed, the generated value is a database concern.  Until the database has committed the record, that value is by design not known.  Actively trying to peer into database concerns from the code is a sign of a more significant design problem.